# Example of a pair of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this example of random variables

$$f_{XY}( x,y) =  \begin{cases}
   cx & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \ , \ 0 \leq y \leq 1  \\
   0 & \text{other}
\end{cases}
$$

> a) determine the $c$ constant, the $ f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ 
>   b) determine the probability $P[X\geq Y]$

I solved the a) like this:

$$ f_{X}(x) = \int_0^1 f_{XY}( x,y) \ dy = \int_0^1 cx \ dy = cx \\
\int_0^1 f_{X}(x) \ dx = \frac{c}{2} \ \implies  c=2 \\
f_{Y}(y) = \int_0^1 f_{XY}( x,y) \ dx = \int_0^1 2x \ dx = 1$$

then

$$f_{X}( x) =  \begin{cases}
   2x &  0 \leq x \leq 1  \\
   0 & \text{other}
\end{cases}~, \qquad
f_{Y}( y) =  \begin{cases}
   1 & 0 \leq y \leq 1  \\
   0 & \text{other}
   \end{cases}
$$

**how can i solve b) ?**

Comment: $P(X>Y)=\iint_{x>y} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$.

Answer (score 1):

> a) determine the $c$ constant, the $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$

Indeed, your solution checks out okay.

- $c=2$
- $f_X(x)=\begin{cases}2x&:&0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
- $f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}1&:&0\leqslant y\leqslant 1\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

> b) determine the probability $P[X≥Y]$

Just integrate the joint probability density function over the intersection of its support and the criteria:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y)&=\iint_{\Bbb R^2} f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathbf 1_{x<y}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\int_0^1\int_0^y2x\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[2ex]&~\vdots\end{align}$$